# How to remove a folder and all its history

Tags: git

I have added a folder with images - by mistake - but I realized this just now. Is there any possibility to remove this folder from that day and on without effecting the rest of the files in any way whatsoever?

Comment: By added, do you mean: staged (`git add`), commited (`git commit`), or pushed to the remote repository?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have pushed them on the repository.

Comment: Does anyone else use that repository? Has anything else been added or changed within the same commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> remove this folder from that day and on without effecting the rest of the files in any way whatsoever?

A filter-branch (mentioned in [leemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545369/leemo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537109/6309)) won't "affect" the file, but will affect the history of the repo.

You will have to do a `git push --force` in order to publish that correction, which means warn other collaborators to reset their own repo to that new origin/master branch.

And the size won't be smaller until you do a

```
git gc
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

And it won't get smaller on the remote side unless you have access to that server and perform the same commands on the bare repo: see "[Clean up large files on git server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31980224/6309)".

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Thanks for that, I'll update my answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what you're folder is called but this is what you are looking for (it assumes the folder is called `img` and only updates the local history)

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf img' --prune-empty HEAD
echo img/ >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Removing images folder from git history'
git gc
```

**NOTE:** `git gc` Cleans up the files from the history so you can free up the space they used

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP also wants to wipe the history.

Comment: @bereal That's where the `filter-branch` comes in.

Comment: This filters the branch history and removes everything matching `img`. Or do you mean wipe the history in its entirety? I cant think of a reason you would want to do that

Comment: Yes, I meant the folder.  You are right, I didn't get it first.